# Why C standards contain many unsafe functions, which are useless?

Tags: c, c99, c89, c11

Why C standards contain many unsafe functions, which are useless (in good programs them don't use) and harmful, for example `getchar`? Why C standard doesn't contain instead of them the useful functions, for example `getch`, and `getche`? It is only one of many examples...

UPD 
I confused: `gets` instead of `getchar`.

Comment: What's wrong with `getchar()`?

Comment: Because the input/output buffer hasn't to do with C, every operating system implements it's way.

Comment: Sounds like another person complaining about his betters not being perfect.  C is arguably the most successful language of all time.

Comment: @Bush Elaborate please how `getchar()` is unsafe

Comment: @Ramy Al Zuhouri But then why there is getchar?

Comment: By "unsafe", OP means it doesn't perform a single unbuffered, raw-mode keypress read on the terminal like OP wants....

Comment: @duffymo I don't say that the C is bad. I don't understand why from time to time in the standard don't get rid from useless and don't add the useful.

Comment: It does get new ones. The recent C standard, C11, has "bound checking interfaces" in annex K (normative) which contains many "safe" functions with `_s` in the name. These might be to your liking.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with getchar(), usually the most problematic function is scanf, but I don't know on what system he compiles.

Comment: @R.. That's hardly qualify as "unsafe" to my taste :)

Comment: @qrdl I confused: `gets` instead of `getchar`.

Comment: @Bush `gets()` is just one unsafe function and it is deprecated in C99, so your premise about `standard contains many unsafe functions` is just plain wrong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean `gets`? To not break old programs. The road to obsoleteness is long.
  And besides, it *has* been deprecated.

Comment: But why not added the `getch`, and `getche`? To whom do they hinder? Why to pull for itself a sore tail? Why not to cut off it?

Comment: @Bush: There are many good reasons not to add them. One is that many historical systems have functions by the same names which do completely different things; attempting to standardize one of those would be unacceptable to everybody else. Another reason is that these functions operate at a completely different level from stdio. The curses `getch` function, for example, works with curses key codes, not characters, and is not compatible with stdio buffering.

Comment: >Do you mean gets?
@Carl Norum Yes, I am sorry, I confused with `gets`.

Answer (score 2):

`gets` is deprecated in C99 and has been **removed** in C11.

C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) Forward/6

> removed the gets function ()

Comment: Thank you, it is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't implement getch() [reading without buffering] on a teletype (terminal that looks like a typewriter). Or any type of terminal where the data is stored in the terminal until you hit enter.

There are functions that do this sort of things, but remember that C is a language that is supposed to "run on anything".

`gets` was part of the standard library many years ago, so it has to stay - otherwise, old code won't compile, and a lot of people like to use old code (because it's a lot of work to fix up 1000000 lines of messy code that used to work!)